# Show that the summation of a set converges (really hard to format)

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $\{a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots, a_k\}$ is a set, then the sequence $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^k a_i^n \right)^{1/n}$$ converges.

Comment: I have added LaTeX code for your question. Please verify that I formatted your question correctly.

Comment: I think you want to assume all the $a_i$'s are non-negative.  The sequence $((-1)^n + 1^n)^{1/n}$, for example, doesn't converge.

Comment: This is the format I was implying, yes. thank you @baudolino.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** I take that $a_i\geq 0$.

Let $A=\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$. Can you show that $$A\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^k a_i^n \right)^{1/n}\leq k^{1/n}\cdot A$$

holds?

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the properties of the [Generalized mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean), namely that:
$$max(a_1,a_2\ldots a_k) =M_\infty > M_n = \left(\sum a_i^n\right)^{1/n} $$

Comment: unfortunately @nbubis, I am not at liberty to be using this theorem. I'm still very early in my book and so have few results at my disposal. all I really have is the definition of monotone, definition of increasing, and the fact that a sequence converges if all of its subsequences converge.